# Multiple values for a parameter jQuery BBQ

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

I need to create a hash url like 
http://www.example.com/#filter=1&filter=2

How do I use jQuery.bbq.pushState function to store multiple values with a single id(filter in this case) for attaining the above url structure?

Or are there any other methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.example.com/#filter=1,2  ?